# difference between "bash -eu" . and "bash -e"

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

Apologies if this is a repost. I did search (no luck) before posting this.

"bash -e" will error/fail if there is any error. Doesn't it include the "bash -u" condition? If a parameter is not set won't a command using that parameter fail and caught by "bash -e" ?

Isn't "bash -eu"  equal to "bash -e" in that case?

Comment: No - just try it on the command line: `set -e; echo $idontexist` - the exit status of this is 0, and `set -e` doesn't care.

Comment: `-eu` is how we do it in Europe. The `u` helps with accidental references to undefined variables. `e` fails the script on unchecked errors. Read the friendly manual #rtfm.

Answer (score 5):

No, `bash -e` (`bash` started with the `errexit` shell option set) is not the same as `bash -e -u` (`bash` started with both `errexit` and `nounset` set).

Example:

```
$ bash -e -c 'echo "hello $string"'
hello
$ echo "$?"
0
```

```
$ bash -e -u -c 'echo "hello $string"'
bash: string: unbound variable
$ echo "$?"
1
```

Using an unset variable under *only* `errexit` is not an error, it just expands to an empty string.

Also:

```
$ bash -u -c 'echo "hello $string"'
bash: string: unbound variable
$ echo "$?"
127
```

This shows a subtle difference between `-e` and `-u`.  With only `-u`, `bash` exits with code 127, which translates into a "command not found" error. With both `-e` and  `-u`, `bash` exits with a more generic error code of 1.

---

These things holds true for the POSIX `sh` shell as well, although I don't believe that the 127 exit status is *explicitly* required for the last example.